# Redux in ReactJS App updates state only when you dispatch the same actions twice error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is my code:

1. ChartActions.js

> ```
> import * as types from './ChartTypes.js';
> export function chartData(check){
>    return { type: types.CHART_DATA,check };
> }
> ```

2. ChartTypes.js

> `export const CHART_DATA = 'CHART_DATA';`

3. ChartReducers.js

> ```
> import { 
>     CHART_DATA,
> }from './ChartTypes.js';
>
> const initialState = {
>     chartData : [],
> }
>
> export default function ChartReducers(state = initialState, action) {
>     switch (action.type) {                    
>         case  CHART_DATA : 
>           return Object.assign({}, state, {
>               chartData : action.check
>           });           
>         default:
>             return state;
>     }
> }
> ```

I am so sure that I setup redux quite accurate and it works perfectly. My problem is:

In a component A I dispatch a function:

```
handleClick(){
    this.props.ChartActions.chartData("test string")    
}
```

so in theory, a component B in my project will receive the string  "test string" right after the handeClick function triggered, like this

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(){
      console.log(this.props.chartData) // test string
   }
```

But I have no idea why SOMETIMES (it only happens sometimes) I have to trigger handleClick function TWO times in component A so that the component B could be able to get the updated state (in this example, it is "test string").  I supposed it's a bug.

I need the component B will receive the updated state (i.e "test string") RIGHT AFTER the handleClick is triggered only ONE TIME.

I have a container:

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> import { connect } from 'react-redux';
> import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
> import * as ChartActions from '../../components/center-menu/services/ChartActions.js';
> import CenterMenu from '../../components/center-menu/center-menu-index.js'
> import RightMenu from '../../components/right-content/right-content-index.js'
>
> class Home extends Component {
>   render() {
>     return (
>         <div>
>              <CenterMenu
>                 ChartActions = {this.props.ChartActions}
>              />
>              <RightMenu
>                 ChartProps={this.props.ChartProps}
>              />
>         </div>              
>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
>
> function mapStateToProps(state) {
>     return {
>         ChartProps: state.ChartReducers
>     };
> }
>
> function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
>     return {
>         ChartActions: bindActionCreators(ChartActions, dispatch),
>     };
> }
>
> export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
> ```

Here is the component A where I fire an actions:

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
>
>
>
> class CenterMenu extends Component {
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
>         constructor(props) {
>           super(props);
>
>           this.state = {};
>         }
>
>     }
>     handleClick(){
>         this.props.ChartActions.chartData('test string')
>     }
>     render() {
>         return (
>
>             <div className="center_menu" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
>                 Some stuff
>             </div>
>         )
>     }
> }
>
>
>
> export default CenterMenu;
> ```

And in another component B:

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
>
>
>
> class RightMenu extends Component {
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
>         constructor(props) {
>           super(props);
>
>           this.state = {};
>         }
>
>     }
>     componentWillReceiveProps(){
>         console.log(this.props.ChartProps.chartData, "right here")
>     }
>     render() {
>         return (
>
>             <div className="center_menu">
>                 Some stuff
>             </div>
>         )
>     }
> }
>
>
>
> export default RightMenu;
> ```

Weird thing:

In Component A, if I trigger the handleClick function by clicking in a div tag, it fires an action that change the initial state to "test string"

But...

In the component B the statement

> console.log(this.props.ChartProps.chartData, "right here")

show empty string first like this:

> right here

But when I trigger the handleClick function the SECOND TIME  in component A , then in component B, in the statement

> console.log(this.props.ChartProps.chartData, "right here")

it show the following:

> test string   "right here"

which is the result I want to achieve.

But I don't understand why I HAVE TO trigger the handleClick function twice. I need it by one click.

Comment: Give us some more code from component A and B, like how you connect them

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov I did, pls check again thank so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `Home` component doesn't rerender the children. Try keeping `ChartProps` in a state in `Home` like so:

```
class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    ChartProps: null //you can use some default value, this might cause undefined is not an object error in you children
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { ChartProps } = this.props
    this.setState(() => ({ ChartProps }))
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const { ChartProps } = this.props
    this.setState(() => ({ ChartProps }))
  }

  render() {
    const { ChartProps } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <CenterMenu
          ChartActions={this.props.ChartActions}
        />
        <RightMenu
          ChartProps={ChartProps}
        />
      </div>

    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    ChartProps: state.ChartReducers
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    ChartActions: bindActionCreators(ChartActions, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: @CuongHoang Great! Accept the answer for future references